# ASP.NET MVC: Referencing Foreign key to IdentityUser. Table with FK Shows Null after Inserting Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm quite new to ASP.NET MVC. What I've made is a Register and Login from the Scaffolding Views.

Another table I've made is "Feedback" and it has a foreign key "UserId" referencing to ASP.Net Identity User which is the "Id" field. Once I've done creating a Create() View for the feedback, it has been successfully saving the 2 fields that I want but not the UserId, which just shows null.

How do I even work with this to reference the Id of the current user to the feedback table... Here are my code

Feedback Model

```
public class Feedback
    {
        [Key]
        public int FeedbackId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Subject Required.")]
        public string Subject { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Feedback> Feedbacks { get; set; }
    }
```

FeedbackController

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(Feedback record)
        {
            var item = new Feedback()
            {
                Subject = record.Subject,
                Text = record.Text,
        };

            _context.Feedbacks.Add(item);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

[what inserts into the sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIVjI.png)

edit-
[relationship in sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNXM5.png)

Answer (score 0):

I FINALLY SOLVED IT IM SO FREAKING HAPPY.
After hours and hours of searching I finally found an answer.

So what I did was to add this namespace `using System.Security.Claims;`

and in my FeedbackController, these are the changes that I made

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(Feedback record)
        {
            var Id = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            var user = new ApplicationUser();
            var item = new Feedback()
            {
                Subject = record.Subject,
                Text = record.Text,
                DateTime = System.DateTime.Now,
                UserId = Id,
            };

            _context.Feedbacks.Add(item);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

It seems that this line of code `User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);` stores the Id(PK) from the AspNetUsers and using it to set the UserId(FK) Field from another table works.

Comment: One thing I could not solve is when I've added a new Field "FullName" into the AspNetUsers Table, that is when I don't know how to reference the current logged in user to make use of that field.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found an answer. If you added a custom Field to the IdentityUser, let say MessengerLink, Address, or FullName.

You can call that address by using this code.

```
var user = _context.Users.Where(u => u.Id == Id).SingleOrDefault();
var msger = user.Messenger;
var fname = user.FullName;
var address = user.Address;
```

Thank you all! :D